# saltstack equivalent of puppet last_run_summary.yaml

Tags: saltstack

Does Salt have the equivalent of Puppet's [last_run_summary.yaml](https://puppet.com/blog/puppet-monitoring-how-to-monitor-success-or-failure-of-puppet-runs)? If not, what's the suggested way to monitor the success or failure of executions on individual salt minions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a reasonable way to get this information written to the file system.
We can modify the minion config (on Linux I believe the default location is `/etc/salt/minion`) to add:

`returners: rawfile_json`

This will result in one JSON object per line being logged. Documented [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/all/salt.returners.rawfile_json.html). The default output file location for this is `/var/log/salt/events`.
The JSON object has fields which we can use:
`retcode`, `success`, and `fun` (the function name). In my case I want to filter for `fun = "state.apply"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [jobs.exit_success](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.jobs.html#salt.runners.jobs.exit_success) command to do so

The only thing is you need to retrieve the job_id first

```
salt-run jobs.list_jobs
salt-run jobs.exit_success <jobid>
```